# Bigquery standard SQL: Filter out the duplicates while keeping the sequence of one column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm writing query in BigQuery trying to export the distinct pages a session visited, following the sequence of when (PageVisit_time) the pages are visited (ascending), below is what I wrote and the outputs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
fullVisitorId||'.'||visitStartTime||'.'||visitNumber AS session_id, 
page.pagePath,
MIN(DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime),"America/New_York"), INTERVAL hits.time MILLISECOND))  AS PageVisit_time

from `xx.xx.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.type = "PAGE"
and date = '20220403' 
group by 1,2
order by 1, 3 desc
```

Outputs of the above query:

| session_id | pagePath | PageVisit_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | /point | 2022-04-03T11:26:13.719000 |
| 123 | /point | 2022-04-03T11:27:15.653820 |
| 123 | /point-ad | 2022-04-03T11:34:10.000000 |
| 123 | /point-ad-next | 2022-04-03T12:38:15.82340 |
| 123 | /point | 2022-04-03T12:50:18.123820 |

I want to keep only distinct session_id and pagePath in the final output, and I also want to make suer pagePath is listing follow the same sequence (ascending by PageVisit_time), any suggestions on how to make it work?

Ideal output:

| session_id | pagePath |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | /point |
| 123 | /point-ad |
| 123 | /point-ad-next |

Comment: so why use the dates at all?

Comment: @nbk Because in real practice we are looking at a much bigger time range, 4/3 is just an example here.

Comment: your query without the DISTINCT should give not the result you posted, it would give only three rows, so it is quite hard to understand why you want

Comment: because just by select distinct of the first output (those 5 records), the result of the order of page path is now following page_visit_time order. and that's what I mainly wanted to resolve.

Comment: i do understand your query, what i can't believe you will get your result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you want to get the first row for each pagePath in the session, and also the other attributes from these events.
If I'm correct, you can use array_agg function to get the first row you want. I'm simplifying the query here, so you can modify it based on your needs.

```
SELECT 
    fullVisitorId||'.'||visitStartTime||'.'||visitNumber AS session_id, 
    page.pagePath,
    array_agg(struct(
        visitStartTime,
        attribute1,
        attribute2,
        attribute
    ) order by visitStartTime limit 1)[offset(0)] as attr
from `xx.xx.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.type = "PAGE"
    and date = '20220403' 
group by 1,2
order by session_id, attr.visitStartTime
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for thanks so much Sabri! Accepted the answer :)